# From indices to field name in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I would need to get back the value names from indices.
My dataset is as follows

```
try_test = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['apple', 'orange', 'diet', 'energy', 'fire', 'cake'], 
                         'name': ['dog', 'cat', 'mad cat', 'good dog', 'bad dog', 'chicken']})

    word    name
0   apple   dog
1   orange  cat
2   diet    mad cat
3   energy  good dog
4   fire    bad dog
5   cake    chicken
```

Using this function:

```
def func(name):
    matches = try_test.apply(lambda row: (fuzz.partial_ratio(row['name'], name) >= 85), axis=1)
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x]

try_test.apply(lambda row: func(row['name']), axis=1)
```

I got the following values:

```
0    [0, 3, 4]
1       [1, 2]
2       [1, 2]
3       [0, 3]
4       [0, 4]
5          [5]
```

I would like to have the word fields instead of the indices.

Expected output:

```
0    [apple, energy, fire]
1       [orange, diet]
2       [orange, diet]
3       [apple, energy]
4       [apple, fire]
5          [cake]
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: index back into the df using `df.loc[rows,<col_name>]`?

Comment: where should I include it? Could you please show me?

Comment: You can do it within/outside your func;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function from `i` to `try_test.word[i]`

```
def func(name):
    matches = try_test.apply(lambda row: (fuzz.partial_ratio(row['name'], name) >= 85), axis=1)
    return [try_test.word[i] for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting a KeyError when I try to apply the function with some rows of my dataset. Do you know how I can avoid this error? (KeyError: 23) Can you please show me how to apply the function above to my dataset?

Comment: reset your index?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro try reset_index before running , try_test= try_test.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: `try_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

After getting the df with the indexes, just indexing the df again should solve your problem. THis you can do outside your func or within your func as well IMO;

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [3]: try_test = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['apple', 'orange', 'diet', 'energy', 'fire', 'cake'],  
   ...:                          'name': ['dog', 'cat', 'mad cat', 'good dog', 'bad dog', 'chicken']})                                                                                                                                                      

In [4]: try_test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[4]: 
     word      name
0   apple       dog
1  orange       cat
2    diet   mad cat
3  energy  good dog
4    fire   bad dog
5    cake   chicken

In [5]: rows = [0,3,4]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [6]: try_test.loc[rows, 'word']                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[6]: 
0     apple
3    energy
4      fire
Name: word, dtype: object

In [7]: try_test.loc[rows, 'word'].values.tolist()                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
['apple', 'energy', 'fire']
```

Comment: How could I extend to all the data, without specify rows as a sublist?

Comment: I think you are better off with modifying the function itself as the other answer showed; Because the way i wrote, it's gonna be little hectic but it will work for sure;